# pandoc error: divide by zero

Tags: python-sphinx, pandoc

I am writing a book. The orginal format is reST, and sphinx is used to generate HTML/epub format. However it has to be converted into docx, since the editor think it is a good raw format for Indesign in their daily process.

A shell script is used:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ./source
echo foreword
pandoc -o foreword.docx foreword.rst
echo ch001
pandoc -o ch001.docx ch001.rst
echo ch002
pandoc -o ch002.docx ch002.rst
echo ch002b
pandoc -o ch002b.docx ch002b.rst
echo ch003
pandoc -o ch003.docx ch003.rst
echo ch004
pandoc -o ch004.docx ch004.rst
echo ch005
pandoc -o ch005.docx ch005.rst 
echo ch006
pandoc -o ch006.docx ch006.rst
echo ch007
pandoc -o ch007.docx ch007.rst
echo ch008
pandoc -o ch008.docx ch008.rst
echo ch009
pandoc -o ch009.docx ch009.rst
echo futureplan
pandoc -o futureplan.docx futureplan.rst

mv *.docx ../release/

cd ../
```

I got the following result from console:

```
foreword
ch001
ch002
ch002b
ch003
pandoc: divide by zero
ch004
ch005
pandoc: divide by zero
ch006
pandoc: divide by zero
ch007
pandoc: divide by zero
ch008
pandoc: divide by zero
ch009
pandoc: divide by zero
futureplan
```

Any document which was complainted for divide by zero has only 30B in file size.

Please tell me know to locate and fix that error. I can not find any clue from documentation and group.

Maybe it is a bug, but I have to avoid this issue since the scheduler is very tight.

Comment: try the newest pandoc version and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I tried to reduce the size of the document every time, and finally the very first image file tag in reST is considered as the root cause. If I rename all image tag into plain text. There is no error report. I have no idea if the anything to do with the format of the included pix. I planed to use different format to test it with new pandoc release.

Comment: Update: I tried to install a newer version of pandoc. But 1) No off-the-shelf 32bit Linux 2) Winodws MSI installer doesn't install anything 3) source building failed due to a lot of errors by stack.... It is not a good day. So far the last method is find a new PC with 64bit OS to try out.

Comment: Update2: Finally I got a latest 64bit Windows pandoc, now divide by zero is disappear. Though there some other complains and issues like missing pictures. So I give up convert direct path, from reST to docx, but using a medium, using Sphinx convert reST to HTML, then using pandoc to convert HTML to docx.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I downloaded latest version pandoc for Windows.

Since rest to docx will drop some pictures, I use another work around method.
reST to HTML by sphinx, HTML to docx by pandoc.

Comment: with pandoc you can always convert reST -> markdown, clean up the markdown, then markdown -> docx. (pandoc's markdown maps basically one-to-one to pandoc's internal document representation.) that way you can also find out whether the issues are in the reST reader or docx writer and submit bug reports...